# NoMethodError when using string.scan under Ruby

Tags: ruby, twitter

I'm writing a little script with Ruby that takes twitter posts and breaks them up even further.  When I send a normal string (non-twitter) against it, it works fine and split strings that are bigger than 32 characters.  But for some reason I get an error like this when using the twitter data:

> in `chunk': private method`scan' called for ["twituser: foo. #yolo"]:Array (NoMethodError)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'


Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key       = ''
  config.consumer_secret    = ''
  config.oauth_token        = ''
  config.oauth_token_secret = ''
  #config.auth_method        = :oauth
end

def chunk(string,size)
        string.scan(/.{1,#{size}}/)
end

twitterfeed = Twitter.search("#yolo", :count => 1, :result_type => "recent").results.map do |status|
        "#{status.from_user}: #{status.text}"
end

twitterfeed.join
puts "#{twitterfeed}\n"

sendchunks = chunk(twitterfeed,32)
sendchunks.each do |string|
        puts "\x52\x31\x10\xAC\x4E\x31\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x35\x41\x0E" + string + "\x0D\x0A"
        puts "#{string}\n"
        sleep(10)
end
puts "done\n"
```

So why the difference?  I'm new to ruby so I'm trying to get my head around the difference in how variable types work.  A normal string works but even after array to string conversion it horks.

Thanks!

[Edited with the full code of script as the answers are getting off track causing things to burst]

Solution was to do the following:

```
twitterfeed_string = twitterfeed.join
puts "#{twitterfeed_string}\n"
sendchunks = chunk(twitterfeed_string,32)
```

Comment: Read the error come on. `private methodscan' called for #Array`. It is an **ARRAY**.

Comment: but i'm converting with the twitterfeed.join('').to_s ?

Comment: `join` makes a string out of the array...

Comment: I don't think the issue is string conversion (because that works fine) but the private method/nomethoderror in string.split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says `private methodscan' called for #Array`. This is because you are not storing the result of `twitterfeed.join('').to_s` anywhere. You are then passing `twitterfeed` as an array to your `chunk` method.
You are not overriding `twitterfeed`.

You probably want to do

```
twitterfeed_as_string = twitterfeed.join
sendchunks = chunk(twitterfeed_as_string , 32)
```

Comment: Code Modified but same issue --- in 'chunk': private method 'scan' called for ["blah blah #yolo"]:Array (NoMethodError) - why is scan throwing the NoMethodError?  Same issue I believe.

Comment: @jfalcon same issue because you modified somehow what I wrote or put something in between. Update your question with your most recent code.